# How can I access the "src/main/resources/" folder in Android/Iphone - GluonHQ JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, gluon-mobile, deeplearning4j

I have created a Deep-Learning project called Deeplearning2C. The purpose with that application is to generate a neural network to pure C-code and also train/evaluate neural networks in a easy graphical way.

https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Deeplearning2C

For desktop such as Linux, it works perfect. But for Android 4.4 and Android 6.0. I found out that there is some issues. I implemented my application onto a Samsung Galaxy S3. The issue on that phone is that when I press the text box inside this pop-up. Only press to write in text. No more.

[image]

The application stops and shut down.

On Samsung Galaxy S5 Neo, the application stops when I generate a new model. It stops because of the marked line of code below. I'm trying to move a file from the resource folder `src/main/resources/BLAS/` , to `/root/Documents/Deeplearning2CStorage/cgeneration/<modelName>/BLAS/<fileName>.<fileExtension>`

```
fileHandler.createNewFile(cPath + modelName + "/" + modelName + ".c", true);
        fileHandler.createNewFile(cPath + modelName + "/" + modelName + ".h", true);
        File[] files = new File("src/main/resources/BLAS/").listFiles(); // <--- Here I assume that it breaks
        try {
            for(File file : files) {
                fileHandler.createNewFile(cPath + modelName + "/BLAS/" + file.getName(), true); 
                Files.copy(file, fileHandler.loadNewFile(cPath + modelName + "/BLAS/" + file.getName()));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            dialogs.exception("Cannot create initial C-files for BLAS", e);
        }
```

The java class file where this code is included, can be found in `ModelsPresenter.java` inside the project.

**Question:**

How can I access the "src/main/resources/" folder inside my application when it's installed on Android/Iphone?

Comment: On runtime there is no `src/main/resources`, all the files are packed into the jar/apk. You need to access them with `getResourcesAsStream()`, like in this [sample](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/blob/master/gluon-SQLite/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/sqlite/BasicView.java#L194). Note the use of `copyDatabase` to move a file from "resources" to the private storage that your app has assigned.

Comment: As for debugging, the easiest thing to do is to run `adb logcat -v threadtime` from a terminal with your device connected, you will get all the output from your app and others.

Comment: @JoséPereda I don't need to use SQLite for that?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't say you have to use SQLite. I was just pointing out a Gluon Mobile sample that deals with files from resources...

Comment: @JoséPereda like this `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("BLAS")` ? This will return InputStream.

Comment: You can use something like `copyDatabase` to transform that inputStream into files in a required location within the private storage of your app. I suggest you have a look at that SQLite sample to understand what I mean.

Comment: Just use `/`... https://www.baeldung.com/reading-file-in-java

Comment: @JoséPereda Now it's working. I have tested the application onto Android 6.0.1 and I can train, evaluate and generate a neural network in C-code now :) Here is my solution thanks to you. https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Deeplearning2C/blob/51f409288b125d0fd55623229c5160988ec86ba5/Deeplearning2CApp/src/main/java/se/danielmartensson/views/ModelsPresenter.java#L219 For Android 4.4.4, it won't work because Android 4.4.4 do not like the AlertBox class for some reason.